# python urllib2 - reading a page after table loaded

Tags: python, html, urllib2

I am trying to read a page with urllib2, in order to extract data from the page. After an update from the website, I think the table I am interested in is now generated per load, and when I am reading the url with urllib2 this table is empty in the html I am getting.

My current code is :

```
url = 'http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/natural-gas/lng-japan-korea-marker-platts-swap.html' 
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers = hdr)
html = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
table = soup.find_all(id="quotesFuturesProductTable1")[0]
```

My headers for additional info :

```
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
```

I get the table but it is empty. I understand that I may have to call another script in the page but can not find out which one.

Comment: If the page is dynamic, containing an empty table and then some JavaScript to call out to a server to fill in that table, you have to reproduce the work done by that JavaScript. You may be able to do this by running a headless browser engine, or maybe just a JavaScript interpreter. If the JS code is simple enough, you may be able to read it and translate it to Python. If the pattern of requests is simple enough, you may be able to read it off the developer panel in your browser and reproduce it without even reading the JS. But you have to do something like one of these.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the data you're loking for is located at `http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/Quotes/Future/7049/G`.

You're in luck, that's already JSON, so you don't even need BeautifulSoup, you just have to parse it with the `json` module. Your code becomes:

```
url = "http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/Quotes/Future/7049/G"
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=hdr)
data = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
parsed_data = json.loads(data)
```

Don't forget the `json` import ! I should also mention as an alternative the excellent [requests](http://python-requests.org/%20requests) package that has a simpler API than `urllib2` and comes with JSON parsing for free.

**Note**: This is kind of weak as it will break as soon as they change their URL, but with web scraping that's a pretty much unavoidable problem.

Comment: Thank you, that works very well and that is very simple. 
I now see where you got the url where the data comes from but how did you get it? I can see it in the source but couldn't find it with the F12 table of Chrome…

Comment: I used Firefox's builtin debug tool but that shouldn't be any different. I just inspected the requests going on. When I saw one with "Quotes" in its url I tried to open it and that was it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the site is dynamic, you can use `selenium` to trigger the front-end scripts to populate the DOM:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/natural-gas/lng-japan-korea-marker-platts-swap.html')
table_data = [i.text for i in soup(d.page_source, 'lxml').find_all(re.compile('th|td'))]
header = table_data[7:18]
table = table_data[18:]
final_data = [dict(zip(header, table[i:i+12])) for i in range(0, len(table), 12)]
```

Output:

```
[{u'Volume': u'0', u'Updated': u'08:18:58 CT 10 Apr 2018', u'Hi / Low Limit': u'7.975 / 4.975', u'Last': u'-', u'Prior Settle': u'7.155', u'Charts': u'\n\nShow Price Chart\n\n', u'Month': u'\nMAY 2018\n', u'High': u'-', u'Low': u'-', u'Open': u'-', u'Change': u'-'}, {u'Volume': u'7.600 / 4.600', u'Updated': u'\nJUL 2018\n', u'Hi / Low Limit': u'08:18:58 CT 10 Apr 2018', u'Last': u'-', u'Prior Settle': u'-', u'Charts': u'-', u'Month': u'\n\nShow Price Chart\n\n', u'High': u'-', u'Low': u'0', u'Open': u'-', u'Change': u'7.525'}, {u'Volume': u'08:18:58 CT 10 Apr 2018', u'Updated': u'\n\nShow Price Chart\n\n', u'Hi / Low Limit': u'\nAUG 2018\n', u'Last': u'7.575', u'Prior Settle': u'-', u'Charts': u'-', u'Month': u'-', u'High': u'0', u'Low': u'7.575 / 4.575', u'Open': u'-', u'Change': u'-'}, {u'Volume': u'\nSEP 2018\n', u'Updated': u'-', u'Hi / Low Limit': u'\n\nShow Price Chart\n\n', u'Last': u'-', u'Prior Settle': u'-', u'Charts': u'7.600', u'Month': u'-', u'High': u'7.540 / 4.540', u'Low': u'08:18:58 CT 10 Apr 2018', u'Open': u'0', u'Change': u'-'}, {u'Volume': u'\n\nShow Price Chart\n\n', u'Updated': u'-', u'Hi / Low Limit': u'-', u'Last': u'-', u'Prior Settle': u'0', u'Charts': u'-', u'Month': u'7.650', u'High': u'08:18:58 CT 10 Apr 2018', u'Low': u'\nOCT 2018\n', u'Open': u'7.540 / 4.540', u'Change': u'-'}, {u'Volume': u'-', u'Updated': u'8.750', u'Hi / Low Limit': u'-', u'Last': u'-', u'Prior Settle': u'7.740 / 4.740', u'Charts': u'-', u'Month': u'-', u'High': u'\nNOV 2018\n', u'Low': u'\n\nShow Price Chart\n\n', u'Open': u'08:18:58 CT 10 Apr 2018', u'Change': u'0'}, {u'Volume': u'-', u'Updated': u'-', u'Hi / Low Limit': u'9.225', u'Last': u'0', u'Prior Settle': u'08:18:58 CT 10 Apr 2018', u'Charts': u'-', u'Month': u'-', u'High': u'\n\nShow Price Chart\n\n', u'Low': u'-', u'Open': u'\nDEC 2018\n', u'Change': u'8.500 / 5.500'}, {u'Volume': u'9.700', u'Updated': u'-', u'Hi / Low Limit': u'-', u'Last': u'8.960 / 5.960', u'Prior Settle': u'\nJAN 2019\n', u'Charts': u'0', u'Month': u'-', u'High': u'-', u'Low': u'-', u'Open': u'\n\nShow Price Chart\n\n', u'Change': u'08:18:58 CT 10 Apr 2018'}, {u'Volume': u'-', u'Updated': u'-', u'Hi / Low Limit': u'-', u'Last': u'08:18:58 CT 10 Apr 2018', u'Prior Settle': u'\n\nShow Price Chart\n\n', u'Charts': u'9.100 / 6.100', u'Month': u'0', u'High': u'-', u'Low': u'9.325', u'Open': u'-', u'Change': u'\nFEB 2019\n'}, {u'Volume': u'-', u'Updated': u'0', u'Hi / Low Limit': u'-', u'Last': u'\nMAR 2019\n', u'Prior Settle': u'-', u'Charts': u'08:18:58 CT 10 Apr 2018', u'Month': u'9.150 / 6.150', u'High': u'9.175', u'Low': u'-', u'Open': u'-', u'Change': u'\n\nShow Price Chart\n\n'}, {u'Volume': u'-', u'Updated': u'8.215 / 5.215', u'Hi / Low Limit': u'0', u'Last': u'\n\nShow Price Chart\n\n', u'Prior Settle': u'-', u'Charts': u'\nAPR 2019\n', u'Month': u'08:18:58 CT 10 Apr 2018', u'High': u'-', u'Low': u'-', u'Open': u'7.555', u'Change': u'-'}, {u'Volume': u'0', u'Updated': u'08:18:58 CT 10 Apr 2018', u'Hi / Low Limit': u'7.670 / 4.670', u'Last': u'-', u'Prior Settle': u'7.000', u'Charts': u'\n\nShow Price Chart\n\n', u'Month': u'\nMAY 2019\n', u'High': u'-', u'Low': u'-', u'Open': u'-', u'Change': u'-'}, {u'Volume': u'7.245 / 4.245', u'Updated': u'\nJUL 2019\n', u'Hi / Low Limit': u'08:18:58 CT 10 Apr 2018', u'Last': u'-', u'Prior Settle': u'-', u'Charts': u'-', u'Month': u'\n\nShow Price Chart\n\n', u'High': u'-', u'Low': u'0', u'Open': u'-', u'Change': u'6.745'}, {u'Volume': u'08:18:58 CT 10 Apr 2018', u'Updated': u'\n\nShow Price Chart\n\n', u'Hi / Low Limit': u'\nAUG 2019\n', u'Last': u'6.750', u'Prior Settle': u'-', u'Charts': u'-', u'Month': u'-', u'High': u'0', u'Low': u'6.920 / 3.920', u'Open': u'-', u'Change': u'-'}, {u'Volume': u'\nSEP 2019\n', u'Updated': u'-', u'Hi / Low Limit': u'\n\nShow Price Chart\n\n', u'Last': u'-', u'Prior Settle': u'-', u'Charts': u'6.750', u'Month': u'-', u'High': u'6.920 / 3.920', u'Low': u'08:18:58 CT 10 Apr 2018', u'Open': u'0', u'Change': u'-'}, {u'Volume': u'\n\nShow Price Chart\n\n', u'Updated': u'-', u'Hi / Low Limit': u'-', u'Last': u'-', u'Prior Settle': u'0', u'Charts': u'-', u'Month': u'6.900', u'High': u'08:18:58 CT 10 Apr 2018', u'Low': u'\nOCT 2019\n', u'Open': u'6.920 / 3.920', u'Change': u'-'}, {u'Volume': u'-', u'Updated': u'7.900', u'Hi / Low Limit': u'-', u'Last': u'-', u'Prior Settle': u'7.220 / 4.220', u'Charts': u'-', u'Month': u'-', u'High': u'\nNOV 2019\n', u'Low': u'\n\nShow Price Chart\n\n', u'Open': u'08:18:58 CT 10 Apr 2018', u'Change': u'0'}, {u'Volume': u'-', u'Updated': u'-', u'Hi / Low Limit': u'8.510', u'Last': u'0', u'Prior Settle': u'08:18:58 CT 10 Apr 2018', u'Charts': u'-', u'Month': u'-', u'High': u'\n\nShow Price Chart\n\n', u'Low': u'-', u'Open': u'\nDEC 2019\n', u'Change': u'7.965 / 4.965'}, {u'Volume': u'8.215', u'Updated': u'-', u'Hi / Low Limit': u'-', u'Last': u'8.415 / 5.415', u'Prior Settle': u'\nJAN 2020\n', u'Charts': u'0', u'Month': u'-', u'High': u'-', u'Low': u'-', u'Open': u'\n\nShow Price Chart\n\n', u'Change': u'08:18:58 CT 10 Apr 2018'}, {u'Volume': u'-', u'Updated': u'-', u'Hi / Low Limit': u'-', u'Last': u'18:18:21 CT 09 Apr 2018', u'Prior Settle': u'\n\nShow Price Chart\n\n', u'Charts': u'No Limit / No Limit', u'Month': u'0', u'High': u'-', u'Low': u'8.065', u'Open': u'-', u'Change': u'\nFEB 2020\n'}, {u'Volume': u'-', u'Updated': u'0', u'Hi / Low Limit': u'-', u'Last': u'\nMAR 2020\n', u'Prior Settle': u'-', u'Charts': u'18:18:26 CT 09 Apr 2018', u'Month': u'No Limit / No Limit', u'High': u'7.965', u'Low': u'-', u'Open': u'-', u'Change': u'\n\nShow Price Chart\n\n'}, {u'Volume': u'-', u'Updated': u'No Limit / No Limit', u'Hi / Low Limit': u'0', u'Last': u'\n\nShow Price Chart\n\n', u'Prior Settle': u'-', u'Charts': u'\nAPR 2020\n', u'Month': u'18:18:26 CT 09 Apr 2018', u'High': u'-', u'Low': u'-', u'Open': u'7.360', u'Change': u'-'}, {u'Volume': u'0', u'Updated': u'18:18:25 CT 09 Apr 2018', u'Hi / Low Limit': u'No Limit / No Limit', u'Last': u'-', u'Prior Settle': u'6.805', u'Charts': u'\n\nShow Price Chart\n\n', u'Month': u'\nMAY 2020\n', u'High': u'-', u'Low': u'-', u'Open': u'-', u'Change': u'-'}, {u'Volume': u'No Limit / No Limit', u'Updated': u'\nJUL 2020\n', u'Hi / Low Limit': u'18:18:39 CT 09 Apr 2018', u'Last': u'-', u'Prior Settle': u'-', u'Charts': u'-', u'Month': u'\n\nShow Price Chart\n\n', u'High': u'-', u'Low': u'0', u'Open': u'-', u'Change': u'6.550'}, {u'Volume': u'18:18:38 CT 09 Apr 2018', u'Updated': u'\n\nShow Price Chart\n\n', u'Hi / Low Limit': u'\nAUG 2020\n', u'Last': u'6.500', u'Prior Settle': u'-', u'Charts': u'-', u'Month': u'-', u'High': u'0', u'Low': u'No Limit / No Limit', u'Open': u'-', u'Change': u'-'}, {u'Volume': u'\nSEP 2020\n', u'Updated': u'-', u'Hi / Low Limit': u'\n\nShow Price Chart\n\n', u'Last': u'-', u'Prior Settle': u'-', u'Charts': u'6.500', u'Month': u'-', u'High': u'No Limit / No Limit', u'Low': u'18:18:39 CT 09 Apr 2018', u'Open': u'0', u'Change': u'-'}, {u'Volume': u'\n\nShow Price Chart\n\n', u'Updated': u'-', u'Hi / Low Limit': u'-', u'Last': u'-', u'Prior Settle': u'0', u'Charts': u'-', u'Month': u'6.655', u'High': u'18:18:44 CT 09 Apr 2018', u'Low': u'\nOCT 2020\n', u'Open': u'No Limit / No Limit', u'Change': u'-'}, {u'Volume': u'-', u'Updated': u'7.660', u'Hi / Low Limit': u'-', u'Last': u'-', u'Prior Settle': u'No Limit / No Limit', u'Charts': u'-', u'Month': u'-', u'High': u'\nNOV 2020\n', u'Low': u'\n\nShow Price Chart\n\n', u'Open': u'18:18:31 CT 09 Apr 2018', u'Change': u'0'}, {u'Volume': u'-', u'Updated': u'-', u'Hi / Low Limit': u'8.265', u'Last': u'0', u'Prior Settle': u'18:18:25 CT 09 Apr 2018', u'Charts': u'-', u'Month': u'-', u'High': u'\n\nShow Price Chart\n\n', u'Low': u'-', u'Open': u'\nDEC 2020\n', u'Change': u'No Limit / No Limit'}, {u'Volume': u'\nJUL 2018\n', u'Updated': u'\nSEP 2018\n', u'Hi / Low Limit': u'\nAUG 2018\n', u'Last': u'No Limit / No Limit', u'Prior Settle': u'\n\nMonth\n\n', u'Charts': u'0', u'Month': u'-', u'High': u'\nMAY 2018\n', u'Low': u'\nJUN 2018\n', u'Open': u'Month', u'Change': u'18:18:25 CT 09 Apr 2018'}, {u'Volume': u'\nJUL 2019\n', u'Updated': u'\nSEP 2019\n', u'Hi / Low Limit': u'\nAUG 2019\n', u'Last': u'\nJAN 2019\n', u'Prior Settle': u'\nMAR 2019\n', u'Charts': u'\nDEC 2018\n', u'Month': u'\nNOV 2018\n', u'High': u'\nMAY 2019\n', u'Low': u'\nJUN 2019\n', u'Open': u'\nAPR 2019\n', u'Change': u'\nFEB 2019\n'}, {u'Volume': u'\nJUL 2020\n', u'Updated': u'\nSEP 2020\n', u'Hi / Low Limit': u'\nAUG 2020\n', u'Last': u'\nJAN 2020\n', u'Prior Settle': u'\nMAR 2020\n', u'Charts': u'\nDEC 2019\n', u'Month': u'\nNOV 2019\n', u'High': u'\nMAY 2020\n', u'Low': u'\nJUN 2020\n', u'Open': u'\nAPR 2020\n', u'Change': u'\nFEB 2020\n'}, {u'Volume': u'', u'Updated': u'', u'Hi / Low Limit': u'', u'Last': u'', u'Prior Settle': u'', u'Charts': u'\nDEC 2020\n', u'Month': u'\nNOV 2020\n', u'High': u'', u'Low': u'', u'Open': u'', u'Change': u''}, {u'Last': u'', u'Charts': u'', u'Change': u'', u'Month': u''}]
```